# What is the recommended header for a table column showing date and time?

Tags: tables, column-headers

I have a column in a table that shows date and time and I would like to know what is the recommended header. These are the current choices:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I prefer the last one but it doesn't explicitly say that there is time information while the first two do say that but seem too explicit as it is obvious by looking at the values.

Comment: I'd say the last one too, but it also depends on what the date and time means. Is it the date added, or the date last edited?

Comment: @NGAFD - Date added/created.

Comment: I'd go for 'date added'. That's option three, but with a little bit more context :)

Comment: @NGAFD - Only thing is that it's implied from the other columns that it refers to added/created. Can't show the others just in case...

Comment: For a one word header isn't Time a better word?

Comment: Hey camden_kid, what problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `Last changed` or `Date added`. The user knows he is seeing a date and a time. You don't have to tell him.
The user wants to know what this date means that he is seeing. That's not clear when you just write `Date`.

Comment: I find your suggestion is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to answer your question directly, I would say **go with Date & Time** since it is the most human like.

But as comments at your question suggests (and as it is always with design), it depends. Is this your only date and time on the table entry? It will suffice, but the label itself has very little context "Date added" will do the job the best (if the exact time added is irrelevant). Otherwise use "Time added".

Comment: Other things being equal, **Date & Time** would be my favourite, if **When added** or **Date added** aren't suitable because of what's in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

People can see that the column shows dates and times, so it's unnecessary to tell them what they're seeing. Adding more text to the column header isn't going to increase or decrease users' understanding of what they're looking at.

But you probably have to put something there if your other columns have headers, so use the minimum: "Date." Or if this is, for example, an add date, use "Added" since "date" is implied.